# Time series analysis, with Fourier (...or maybe other method) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

Find repititions and cycles in timestamp serie

I have timestamp data (from around 5000, up to 50.000 timestamps), unevenly distributed over a month or some months:

```
example1 = ['2013-01-01 12:01', '2013-01-01 12:26', '2013-01-01 12:58']
```

The input may be a list as shown, or I could put it in numpy array, maybe force an evenly distribution on minutes:

```
exempel2 = np.array(['2013-01-01 12:01', '2013-01-01 12:02', '2013-01-01 12:03'])
dummyArr = np.array([1, 0, 0])
```

...and have another equally shaped array with a dummy saying if the timestamp in the other array, at the same position (exempel2) is a date/time to consider (1 to consider and zero to not)

My question is, if Fourier transform would be the best option for a Python implementation to find patterns (repitions, cycles) in a timestamp serie, and if Fourier, what would be the best way to do it?

As I said, I am looking for repitions and cycles. A resolution to hours sounds good, but I am a bit unsure. I would simply like to have answers saying that around lunchtime 11-13:00 daily there is a pattern. Every 7th day around 17:00 there is another pattern. There is aybe even a complicated pattern that growth during a year, first 7 day, than 8 days, than 9 days in between. All this from timestamps and maybe with some signifier in the result saying how strong or weak the pattern shows.

Comment: Depends on what type of patterns you are looking for... Fourier is good for periodic repeating patterns, but there are many other types of patterns that Fourier would not be particularly good at highlighting...

Comment: Yes periodic repeating pattern is what i am looking for, any suggestion how solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your time-stamp data to a time series, where the resolution of the time series is equal to the resolution of the time-stamp data.

Your time-stamp examples show one-minute resolution. For that type of data your time series would have one-minute resolution.

You can build an array containing 0 (zeroes) at the places in your time-span where you don't have time-stamp data, and containing 1 (ones) at the places where you have time-stamp data.

This will give you an array of input data for the FFT, something like this array built from random time-stamp data:

[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]

To find the frequency spectrum of your time-stamp data compute the FFT of the array.

This graph represents the above time-stamp array:

[image: Time-stamp data time-series - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

This graph shows the frequency spectrum (FFT) of the above time-stamp array. The large peak is located at 0.002 Hz (cycles per second) which is the fundamental frequency of the input data. In other words, the fundamental period of the time-series is 1/0.002=480 seconds or 8 minutes.

[image: Frequency spectrum of time-stamp data - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

The frequency spectrum shows two lower-magnitude peaks, at f=0.004 Hz and f=0.0065 Hz.

The kind of information you're looking for is better suited to statistical analysis. Fourier analysis cannot provide those kinds of details about your data.

Graphs and FFT done with the [Sooeet FFT calculator](https://sooeet.com/math/online-fft-calculator.php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your resolution is one Minute you could use spectrogram as quick shot to look for patterns:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# convert time stamps to seconds (of UNIX time):
tt_sec = np.array([int(time.mktime(time.strptime(e,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))) for e in example1])
tt = (tt_sec - tt_sec[0]) / 60  # convert to minutes starting at 0

xx = np.zeros(max(tt) + 1) # make sampled array with peaks at time stamps
xx[tt] = 1 

# make spectrogram:
fg = plt.figure(1)
fg.clf()
ax = fg.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.specgram(xx, Fs=1./60)  # spectogram => tune the parameters
fg.canvas.draw()  # do the drawing

plt.show()  # enter interactive loop
```

Read the documentation of matplotlib's `specgram()`  and play with the parameters a bit. If you are to lazy to do a `np.fft.rfft()` you could try `plt.psd()` (a power spectral density). Note that you only get pretty pictures if you have a sufficient number of time stamps.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich! I tried your example to output it on a specgram. However I need something more than an graphical output. I've also tried the numpy fft (fast fourier transformation) on a similar array (ones(1) and zeros(2), but i just dont get how to interpret the resulting float numbers.